# iOS UI hang when change language from app setting

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, multilingual

Dallini UI Reflection Issue -

We are developing a multilingual app, where we need to support English and Arabic Languages, Application also provides an option in setting to change their language preference independent to what they have chosen in Settings of their iPhone. Considering Arabic is right to left language different to English, we are using the following code to change the navigation and UI flow.

UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight or  UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft

However Our Application is lagging and behaving very slow in transition and Table Scrolls just after using this above code. We also tried commenting the above line just to make sure that this is the very same line which is creating this issue. We have also used the analysing tools and saw that after using this code It Increases the over all memory Utilisation.

Please suggest with the correct method/option to be used here as we already achieving the localised String file to manage the content in the application but we also need to reflect the UI and navigation according to the language preference he/she has set on the application independent of what is there in the settings.

Comment: I too am getting the same issue. Narrowed it down to the semantic forcing. Any updates?

Comment: Any update on this issue

Comment: The same issue. Any updates?